# How to get list of routes in sailsjs including blueprints and custom routes

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am newbie sailsjs. I would like to know how to list out all the routes including blueprints and custom routes in the form of JSON.

Answer (score 5):

`sails.config.routes` will get you your defined routes. Currently there is a github issue to collect the rest

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/2659#issuecomment-77417170